# Third party software already installed

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

Im trying to install Tools for Apache Cordova for Visual Studio. In the first step I need to choose which third party dep. to install.
But Ive already installed most of them and already developing on this machine using cordova/node commandline-tools.

Do I need to reinstall all dependencies again? or just some (if yes, which ones?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installer for Tools for Apache Cordova automatically detects which software are already present on the machine. Depending whether you are installing for Visual Studio 2013 or 2015, the experience may seem a little different.

After install completes, all required tools will also be configured as expected. It is best to run the installer once to ensure that there are no incompatibilities, but rest assured, it will not re-install existing compatible software.

Comment: But the installer wants to install Nodejs, apache ant, JDK 7, Android SDK, Google chrome, GIT command line which Im 100% sure Ive installed? Should I deselect these? (it also wants to install SQLite for windows, iTunes and Websocket4Met which I dont think Ive installed)

Comment: I would suggest leaving them selected and only the required tools will get installed.

Answer (score 0):

It is good to let Tools for Apache Cordova for Visual Studio install the 3rd party software because it will install and also configure the machine. If you want to install just the missing software manually then refer the list of dependencies [**here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757054.aspx#ThirdParty) under **Install dependencies manually** section and accordingly install the required software and configure the machine.

Comment: But the installer wants to install Nodejs, apache ant, JDK 7, Android SDK, Google chrome, GIT command line which Im 100% sure Ive installed? Should I deselect these? (it also wants to install SQLite for windows, iTunes and Websocket4Met which I dont think Ive installed)

Comment: Install detection logic will skip the installation of any 3rd party software if it is already installed at required location and version. So you can let installer fill the blank for you. It does not take much to install 3rd party software.